# Django 1.8 static files - DEBUG = False

Tags: python, css, django, static, django-urls

I am trying to make the debug false for my production branch. Please help me out here.

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

from django.conf import settings
import os

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
    )
```

`local.py`

```
DEBUG = False
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

`production.py`

`DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False`

`base.py`

```
   DEBUG = False
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

Why are my CSS files still not loading? Is something wrong with my path to css that is mentioned in urls.py ? Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an FYI, the Django docs [specifically recommend against](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) using `staticfiles` in production.

Comment: Is there any tutorial that shows how to host those files on apache or Nginx?

Comment: Yes. The documentation has full instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's just what you asked it to do.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')} ),
    )
```

And you set `DEBUG = False`. And That's the right thing ofcourse in production!

Django can serve static files in development to rapid development process only, but it's not it's job to serve static files, but some servers like nginx can do it much better performance, caching, ... etc.